# How to figure out what a DTSRun command is doing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

I have taken over a SQL 2000 database. I am trying to figure out what a job is doing. Its command is:

```
DTSRun /~....a big hex string....
```

I have tried to run:

```
DTSRun /~....a big hex string.... /!Y
```

to see what it is doing, but it just repeats the command. Is there a way I can see what this string represents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ave to use `/!X /!C` after the DTS command.

`/!X` ==> Do not run the package

`/!C` ==> copy the results to clipboard

To avoid this, you can create a  SQL Agent Job and choose `CmdExec` as a step type with below commandline:

```
 DTSRun /N"your package name" /S<servername> /E   --- for trusted connection
```

OR

```
DTSRun /N"Your package Name" /S<ServerName> /U<UserName> /P<Password>   --- for SQL authentication
```

As a sidenote, its time for migration to something supported by Microsoft sql 2005, sql 2008 R2 or 2012 along with migrating DTS packages to SSIS.

Refer to :

- [How to identify which DTS Package is being called by scheduled job](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vipulshah/archive/2007/03/12/how-to-identify-which-dts-package-is-being-called-by-scheduled-job.aspx)
- [dtsrun Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)